# Word Doesn't wrap within the box on IE 6,7and8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, word-wrap

I am trying to wrap a text within a box. On Fire Fox it is working fine but not on IE 6,7 n 8. In the style I have written the following code
{font-style:italic;word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word;}

Eg: text is `aaaaaaaaaaaddddddddddddddddcccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddd`
and there are 3 text boxes aligned horizontally. The 3 will contain the above text. The aim is to fit this string in all the three boxes without the string getting spilled over to different box.

Please help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322929/word-wrap-in-css-js

Comment: You might want to try www.doctype.com -- It's a Q&A site for web design, running the stackoverflow Q&A engine.

Comment: It is a J2EE application and I cannot use Table-layout now. Since IE-8 has deprecated the use of expression, hence cannot use expressions also. You can check this on MSDN website.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a width eg width: 300px;