# Can I wrap a long filename?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a table in a fieldset that is not displayed properly (overflow) because of a long file name that I cannot wrap. Is there a way to wrap the file name that is in the table?

```
<table>
    <tr><td>stackoverflow.com/questions/4584756/how-can-i-make-the-datagridviewtextboxcolumn-wrap-to-a-new-line-if-its-text-is-t</td></tr>
</table>
```

**I set the width and overflow style on the td element and still no help. Any other ideas?**

Comment: On what element and what values exactly? Would ellipsis be acceptable?

Comment: I tried a table having <td width="200"> it works fine.

Comment: What browser did you test with? Mine all wrap this example perfectly. Except Amaya and some elderly ones.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this in css  `word-wrap:break-word`  (set a width too. This is CSS3 so might not work in older browsers)

check [word wrap in css / js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322929/word-wrap-in-css-js)

Comment: Not bad. But can you _rap_ a long filename?

Comment: I am now using css3 and word-wrap is not an option :(

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me :

```
<td style='word-break:break-all'>
T1_C50621021900010788086700100001010000000072101000072_E107880867_R115710745_F20190221.pdf
</td>
```

The `word-break:break-all` literally breaks the long filename into pieces, each piece with same width except the last one, with an automatic width chosen by the browser (I guess you can experiment with a custom width).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this selector property and value?

```
element
{
    white-space: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table><tr><td style="overflow-x: auto">your file name</td></tr></table>
```

This will wrap it in next line automatically

Comment: I tried adjusting the width but with no luck. The length of the url would still stretch the width

Comment: I tried the overflow style and I was still unsuccessful. Maybe I am missing something...

Answer (score 0):

In general, a browser will only wrap a text string at a space. So to get it to wrap, you'd have to insert spaces. In principle, you could check if the length is over some value and if so insert a space at a specified point, or add a space after every slash, or something like that. But if the field is updatable, you'd have to be sure to remove these spaces on input. And if the user is going to cut and paste this field, he'd get mysterious extra spaces.

Comment: But the OP's example wraps perfectly with just dashes. Which browser did you test?

Comment: I think this is the issue I am facing. My column is being adjusted based on the longest word regardless of set width. I was just afraid to make changes to the url and make edits on posting

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this, some browsers will not break the string at all by default, some will break after a hyphen “-”, some may also break after a slash “/”. If you really need to have a long filename in a table cell, you need to decide what you want—what would be the least of evils.

After the decision, use `nobr` markup to prevent line breaks and `wbr` markup to allow them, or their character-level or CSS counterparts (which work less widely). There are many nasty details involved; see my page on [preventing and allowing line breaks](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html).

Breaking after “-” is problematic because the reader won’t know whether the hyphen has been introduced in word hyphenation or is part of the filename itself. Then again, does this matter? What is the reader supposed to do with the long filename? In this case, the “filename” looks really like a URL without the “http://” part, and in such cases, it is better to use a descriptive link text (which may wrap freely) and put the URL where it belongs, an `href` attribute.