# why input width 100% in table-layout auto expands in IE7?

Tags: input, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, width, tablelayout

I have a table with constraint width and table cell with percentage width. In the cell i've `input` or `textarea` with `style="width:100%"`, without any margin, padding nor border but with some longer content *without spaces*. Why IE7 and IE6 expand the input to match the content length?

Applying `table-layout: fixed` to the table is not an option -- I relay on the columns expanding to keep their content (e.g. columns with input labels should match labels length).

Full example follows. I've check that this is *valid* HTML5 rendered in standards mode.

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>ie6 ie7 input bug</title>
<style>

  input, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
  }

  table {
    background: yellow;
    width: 500px;
  }

</style>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 15%;">
        <input value="VeryLongTextWithoutSpaces" />
      </td>
      <td> <br/><br/><!-- give height --> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br/> <!-- textarea example -->
  table>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 15%;">
        <textarea>VeryLongTextWithoutSpaces</textarea>
      </td>
      <td> <br/><br/><!-- give height --> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: missing your opening and closing html tags. (not that this solves the problem, just saying.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [textarea with 100% width ignores parent element's width in IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933/textarea-with-100-width-ignores-parent-elements-width-in-ie7)

Comment: @Paul -- my table is used in liquid layout width width 100% (it doesn't change the problem), so i can't apply width in pixels to the `td`. @Grillz <html> tags are optional -- this is valid HTML5, checked using w3 validator

Comment: my own answer about applying `line-height` is not valid for long input without spaces, so I'am reediting my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that applying `line-height` to the input helps **if** the input never contains long words. <strike>This may be enough for me</strike> (I can calculate correct line-height), but other solutions are welcome, as may be more suitable for others.

finally I found the solution here [textarea with 100% width ignores parent element's width in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933/textarea-with-100-width-ignores-parent-elements-width-in-ie7/33950#33950): adding brutal `word-break:break-all;` is a solution.